# VTKLoader: why dont handle CellData?

Tags: three.js, vtk, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei, vtk.js

`
I wanna get VTP file color data ,but i cant get color data in sources code
[three.js sources code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su8rO.png)

```
const piece = json.PolyData.Piece;
const compressed = json.attributes.hasOwnProperty( 'compressor' );

// Can be optimized
// Loop through the sections
const sections = [ 'PointData', 'Points', 'Strips', 'Polys' ];// +['CellData', 'Verts', 'Lines'];
let sectionIndex = 0;
const numberOfSections = sections.length;
```

i wanna get color data in vtp file

at the same time

three.js dont handle this data structure

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="PolyData" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian" header_type="UInt32" compressor="vtkZLibDataCompressor">
  <PolyData>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="50959"                NumberOfVerts="0"                    NumberOfLines="0"                    NumberOfStrips="0"                    NumberOfPolys="99999"               >
      <PointData>
      </PointData>
      <CellData>
      </CellData>
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Points" NumberOfComponents="3" format="appended" RangeMin="9.9461797467"         RangeMax="40.888893559"         offset="0"                   />
      </Points>
      <Verts>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="741612"              />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="741628"              />
      </Verts>
      <Lines>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="741644"              />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="741660"              />
      </Lines>
      <Strips>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="741676"              />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="741692"              />
      </Strips>
      <Polys>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="741708"              />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="1392276"             />
      </Polys>
    </Piece>
  </PolyData>
  <AppendedData encoding="base64">
   _EwAAAACAAAC0VAAAH3IAAB10AACNdAAAp3QAABx0AADlcwAAbHQAAMR0AADndAAA+XQAAOR0AADjdAAApnQAALx0AAAQdQAA13QAAGh0AABwcwAA7EwAAA==eJwMl2VYFGoUhAFFQRRRkBIkVEBBBZF
```

```
<DataArray format="appended"/>
```

```
<AppendedData encoding="base64">
    NdAAAp3QAABx0AADl
<AppendedData/>
```

How can i Loading this format vtp file?
`